# AWS: test ALB with lambda and s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

as described in the image below, I have a `Route53` record that calls an `ALB` that triggers a `Lambda`, and this `Lambda` function will clone some code from a git repository to an `S3 bucket`.
[image]
the `Route53` is in a private hosted zone, so I can't find a way to send a POST request to the A record of `Route53` to trigger the whole process.
is there any way I can test it ?

Comment: Is this supposed to be private service, thus private HZ in R53, or accessible from the internet?

Comment: @Marcin yes it's private and should be accessible to specific users !

Answer (score 0):

[Private Hosted Zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) (HZ) can't be accessed directly from the internet. They are only usable **within VPC**. Fron [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html):

> A private hosted zone is a container that holds information about how you want Amazon Route 53 to respond to DNS queries for a domain and its subdomains **within one or more VPCs** that you create with the Amazon VPC service.

This means that your POST or GET to `www.bla-bla-amazon.com` will not get resolved over the internet, thus you can't call the dns from the internet. For that, as docs write, you need **public** HZ:

> If you want to route traffic for your domain on the **internet**, you use a Route 53 **public** hosted zone. For more information

However, if you want to access the private HZ from outside of a VPC, you can do it indirectly, using **VPN** or **ssh tunnel**. SSH tunnel is easier to use and setup for testing and development purposes. For that to work, you need a public **EC2 instance** in the VPC where your HZ is. From outside of AWS, e.g. home/work, you can setup SSH tunnel with local port forwarding to your EC2, e.g.:

```
ssh -L -i priavte_ssh_key local_port:private_dns_of_your_service:remote_port ec2-user@ec2-instance-ip
```

This way, you will be able to use `http://localhost:local_port` on your home/work computer to access private resources in the VPC.

By the way, if the setup should be private, the ALB should be internal, not internet-facing.

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong, so what I need to do is to create a public EC2 instance within the same VPC as the hosted zone, and then ssh to this instance and from it, I can curl to the A record of the Route53?

Comment: @SlimenTN Yes, if you want to curl from ec2 instance, than its ok. The ssh tunnel is only needed if you want to access your private resources from your home/work computer.

Comment: ok thanks I will give it a try and get back to you :)

Comment: @SlimenTN How did it go?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, it's actually still not working ! I've created an ec2 and in the security groups I've added the SSH and HTTP to have a public IP and ssh to it using "Connect" inside AWS console, but I get an error message `We were unable to connect to your instance. Make sure that your instance’s network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect.`

Comment: @SlimenTN EC2 instance connect requires liberal SG permissions. Can you use regular ssh to access the instance?

Comment: Still can't do it !

Comment: @SlimenTN You can update your question or make new one speicific to the problem of connecting to this instance. Is the instance in public subnet? What are its security groups? Have you modified any subnet NACLs?

Comment: yeah maybe you're right but, for now I've set the ec2 instance inside the private vpc so I can be able to send request to the ALB, but if I put it into another subnet (inside another VPC) I don't think I will be able to run any from it either !

Comment: @SlimenTN If the instance is in private subnet, you will not be able to connect to it using ssh. You can try aws session manager, but this will require NAT gateway and public subnet.